# How do I create an auto-incremented ID inside a <li> tag that's already inside a while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, mysqli

This is my code:

```
function buscarCategs() {

    global $con;

    $buscar_categ = "SELECT * FROM categorias";

    $run_categ = mysqli_query($con, $buscar_categ);


    while ($row_categs = mysqli_fetch_array($run_categ)) {

        $categ_id = $row_categs['categ_id'];
        $categ_titulo = $row_categs['categ_titulo'];

        echo "<li class='celulaCategoriasMenu' onmouseover='javascript:showMenu(); ' onmouseout='javascript:hideMenu();'>$categ_titulo</li><div id='linkMenuAbre' class='linkMenuAbre'>Teste</div>";
    }
}
```

So, how do I create a loop inside this 'while' that generates an auto-incremented ID to be posted on 'echo'?

For example: `echo "<li id='idselector_1'></li>"`, `echo "<li id='idselector_2'></li>"`, `echo "<li id='idselector_3'></li>"`

I tried creating a loop with foreach but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `$id` variable that you increment on every loop.

```
function buscarCategs() {

    global $con;

    $buscar_categ = "SELECT * FROM categorias";

    $run_categ = mysqli_query($con, $buscar_categ);

    $id=1;

    while ($row_categs = mysqli_fetch_array($run_categ)) {

        $categ_id = $row_categs['categ_id'];
        $categ_titulo = $row_categs['categ_titulo'];

        echo "<li id=\"idselector_$id\" class='celulaCategoriasMenu' onmouseover='javascript:showMenu(); ' onmouseout='javascript:hideMenu();'>$categ_titulo</li><div id='linkMenuAbre' class='linkMenuAbre'>Teste</div>";
        $id++;
    }
}
```